# How can I attach a screenshot to a post here?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to reply to a post here that requested a screenshot of my problem.  I have the screenshot, but how can I attach it to my post?

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/203101. Please let me know if you're still having trouble with that.